# Handling brackets created by QUOTENAME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script like below. I am using `QUOTENAME` to construct the name of the table to query. It is giving me an `Invalid object name old.tb2018` error because `QUOTENAME` is generating the table name with brackets like so - `[old.tb2018]`.

I have considered passing tablename as a parameter to `sp_executesql`, but I am using `@old_table_name` in other places in the code. I fear that will create a bunch of duplicate code because of all the other places that is being used in. How do I pass the tablename to `@trunc_success` without it generating an error?

```
DECLARE @YEAR NVARCHAR(4) = year(DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, getdate()))
DECLARE @old_table_name NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @new_table_name NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE @trunc_success NVARCHAR (3000)

SET @old_table_name = QUOTENAME('old.tb' + @year);
SET @new_table_name = QUOTENAME('new.tb' + @year);

SET @trunc_success = '
SELECT 
       CASE 
              WHEN EXISTS 
                     ( 
                            --This should no records
                            SELECT 
                            top 1
                             * 
                            FROM ' + @old_table_name + '
                            ) THEN ''Failed''
              ELSE ''Passed'' 
       END result 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
       CASE 
              WHEN EXISTS 
                     ( 
                            --This should return no records
                            SELECT top 1 * 
                            FROM ' + @new_table_name + '
                ) THEN ''Failed''
              ELSE ''Passed'' 
       END'
print  @trunc_success
EXECUTE sp_executesql @trunc_success
```

Comment: You can't parameterize object names, that includes tables, with dynamic sql. But is your table name really new.tb2019 or is that schema plus the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table's name isn't `old.tb2018` it's `tb2018` and it's on the schema `old`. It should be:

```
DECLARE @old_table_name sysname; --Correct data type for object names
DECLARE @new_table_name sysname; --Correct data type for object names

...

SET @old_table_name = N'old.' + QUOTENAME(N'tb' + @year);
SET @new_table_name = N'new.' + QUOTENAME(N'tb' + @year);

...
```

If you want to quote the schema name too (good when not using a literal value) it would be:

```
QUOTENAME(N'new') + N'.' + QUOTENAME(N'tb' + @year);
```

---

Although I've used `sysname` here, on second though, the idea should be different. It should really be

```
DECLARE @old_table_name sysname; --Correct data type for object names
DECLARE @new_table_name sysname; --Correct data type for object names

...

SET @old_table_name = QUOTENAME(N'tb' + @year);
SET @new_table_name = QUOTENAME(N'tb' + @year);

...
```

And then in your query you'd have:

```
'...FROM old.' + QUOTENAME(@old_table_name) + '...'
```

The reason for this is that `sysname` is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`, however, `QUOTENAME` returns an `nvarchar(258)`; therefore quoting 2 objects, schema and table with a delimitor (`.`), *could* potentially result in an `nvarchar(517)` (258 + 1 + 258). It's therefore better to split the individual parts into their own parameters/variables and use `QUOTENAME` at the point of injection. This will avoid any unexpected truncation if you do have any overly long object names, or have (foolishly) used lots of `]` characters in it's name.

*Of course, the only way you **could** get get a 258 character value for a real object's name from `QUOTENAME` would be if the object's name was made up of 128 `]` characters (`[` for the start and `]` for the end, and 128 `]` characters escaped to `]]`):*

```
SELECT LEN(QUOTENAME(REPLICATE(']',128)));
```

*If you really did have an object named that, I would honestly be questioning your sanity.*